# How do I create Local Group Policy Objects on a standalone machine?

Tags: group-policy

I have to set up five laptops with four users on the them. Two of these users will need the same permissions on them but are used for different purposes. I use MMC snap-ins to edit permissions of Non-Administrators but I need to create a snap-in for the other two that should have identical settings. I don’t want to have to manually enable settings for both users individually; I would like the users in a Local Group so I can create a Local Group Policy Object with the settings I want applied to them.

Creating a user group in gpedit.msc doesn’t work because the created user group doesn’t appear as an option in the Add Snap-In window and I can’t use Group Policy Management because these are standalone machines - not domain machines.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell: you can’t. You have to do your settings for all users individually.